# I am having problems in running my Java program

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java so this question might seem a little stupid, my JDK and [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Overview) are installed in `C:\program files`. I write my program and save it in in my folder, `G:\start`.

Now my program compiles without any error (the .class file is also generated), but when I run my program it says "`unable to locate G:\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg`", so I copy the '`lib`' folder from my JDK folder and paste it in `G:`. Again program compiles without any error, but when I run it, it gives me a new error saying "`unable to locate G:\bin\server\jvm.dll`", so I copy the 'bin' folder to `g:`, but now when I run, it gives me the same error again "`unable to locate G:\bin\server\jvm.dll`". Where am I going wrong?

Comment: and the program iv'e written is a basic "HelloWorldApp", so there are definitely no errors with the code..

Comment: Try to execute `echo %JAVA_HOME%`. What does it return?

Comment: Download IDE from eclipse.org and save yourself the trouble of dealing with stuff like this.

Comment: Well, one place you're going wrong is in failing to write your question in distinct sentences. :-)

Comment: @polygenelubricants He may be writing a very small program, asking him to download a 300 MB IDE is not the right thing and does not answer his question IMHO.

Comment: Don't copy parts of the JRE around, you'll end up with a confusing mess. I'd guess it's an environment variable issue. When you say you "run" your program what, exactly, are you doing?

Comment: @Vaishak: it's the best investment for the long run. And yes, it doesn't answer his question, which is why it's a comment.

Comment: @Peter c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20

Comment: @crazyscot ..i compile using javac HelloWorldApp.java, and run useing java HelloWorldApp

Answer (score 0):

Create an environment variable called JAVA_HOME and point it to the bin directory of your Java installation. Also add the same directory to your PATH variable. This should solve your problem.

PS: JAVA_HOME may not be required, but it will help if you have tomcat and stuff installed.

Comment: If all that has been done, then you should be able to invoke java and javac from any directory in your command prompt. IF that is working, try re-installing JDK, maybe it hasn't been installed properly.
Are you installing JDK or JRE?

Comment: ok i tried re-installing jdk and jre..im getting an error while installing jre which says "there is a problem with this windows installer package.A DLL required for this install to complete could not run.Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Comment: Looks like it has nothing to do with Java then! Uninstall, re download and try. IF that fails, try installing an older version. If memory serves me right, there is an open bug on the server/jvm.dll thing.

Comment: WOW..finally its working.!!!!!..@vaishak..thanks man..older version to the rescue.!!;)

Answer (score 0):

try to save it as a .jar, go to your cmd and use:

java -jar G:\bin\server\jvm.jar

this should work.

Answer (score -2):

The best advise I can give you is to download an IDE to get started. BlueJ is an IDE aimed at getting people started using java and is used in many universities world wide.

take a look at www.bluej.org and you should be up and running in seconds.

Karl

Comment: Like I've said in the above comment, this does not answer the question.